# Obtaining data from either table based on condition

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am gettting data from 2 tables using a UNION. Table1 contains 3 records and Table 2 contains 1 record.
     My query is something like this

```
   SELECT T1.Col1 as Country,T1.Col2 as Airline FROM TABLE1 T1
   UNION
   SELECT T2.Col1 as Country,T2.Col2 as Airline FROM TABLE2 T2;
```

So with this, I get the following result

```
Country  |  Airline
--------------------
 Thailand | Thai Airways
 England  | British Airways
 USA      | US Airlines
 USA      | Cathay Pacific
```

Here, from the first part of UNION, I get the first 3 records (Thai, British and US Airlines).

And from the second part of the UNION I get the Cathay.

But what I really want is, If Table2 contains a value for USA, then I want to take values from Table2, else to take values from Table1. Hence, I want a result of the following type.

```
Country  |  Airline
--------------------
 Thailand | Thai Airways
 England  | British Airways
 USA      | Cathay Pacific
```

I have tried using the CASE statement in mysql.But I can't get the query right. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this SQL query. If country from table1 exist in the table T2 it will not included in result set.

```
SELECT T1.Col1 AS country, T1.Col2 AS airline FROM Table1 T1
WHERE T1.Col1 NOT IN(
   SELECT T2.Col1 FROM Table2 T2)
UNION ALL
SELECT T2.Col1 AS country, T2.Col2 AS airline FROM Table2 T2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `union all` and `not exists`:

```
SELECT T1.Col1 as Country, T1.Col2 as Airline FROM TABLE1 T1
UNION ALL
SELECT T2.Col1 as Country, T2.Col2 as Airline
FROM TABLE2 T2
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table1 t1 WHERE t1.col1 = t2.col1);
```

Although not a consideration for so few records, this query is optimized for larger tables with an index on `TABLE1(col1, col2)`.